# Checking a good connection in Android

Tags: android

Actually, I have a function to check the Internet Connection... that is:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But, if I have a low signal connection.. when I Log In my app and it takes a lot of time, it crashes. How can I do, if i want to check a good or fast connection? Like a timeout condition or something like that..

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you should make sure if (not) on wifi. Then you can check for the desired "speed" by using

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int prov = tm.getNetworkType();

switch (prov) {
        case 1: return GPRS;
        case 2: return EDGE;
        case 3: return UMTS;
        case 8: return HSDPA;
        case 9: return HSUPA;
        case 10:return HSPA;
        default:return UNKNOWN;
        }
```

If you want to check the signal strength of the connected wifi (which does not guarantuee a good network!) you can use

```
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
int level=WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), 5 /** this is how many levels MAX should be displayed **/);
```

as higher the level, as better the signal. You can also use yourwifi.level to get the dBm. -100 to 0. 0 is highest. cheers.

edit: and because of your "app crashes.".
It sounds like that you are doing too many stuff into your main(ui/thread). Make sure it's in a own Thread or an AsyncTask for long-operating stuff.

Comment: No problem. Please do not forget to rate/vote up if this help you resolving your question. Regards, Emanuel